# Setting the Std Err to a messagebox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to find a way to get the std error into a tkinter messagebox. I know I could do it in a text widget, but I think the messagebox is much more fitting for an error. The problem is that the std err prints one line at a time. I have no way of knowing the end of the error message to input them into a messagebox. I came up with a hacky solution, but I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys

class MessageBoxError:

    def __init__(self):
        self.text = ''

    def write(self, string):

        if self.text == '':
            root.after(100, self.testText)

        self.text += string

    def testText(self):
        messagebox.showerror('Error has occured!', message=self.text)
        self.text = ''


root = tk.Tk()
sys.stderr = MessageBoxError()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Create an Error!', command = lambda: 1/0)
btn.grid()

btn2 = tk.Button(root, text='Create an Error 2!', command = lambda: a[5])
btn2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the error message with the traceback module, and then define a custom function for catching errors occuring within the mainloop by overriding the `root.report_callback_exception` attribute

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import traceback

def report_callback_exception(*args):
    err = traceback.format_exception(*args)
    messagebox.showerror('Exception occured', ''.join(err))

root = tk.Tk()
root.report_callback_exception = report_callback_exception

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Create an Error!', command = lambda: 1/0)
btn.grid()

btn2 = tk.Button(root, text='Create an Error 2!', command = lambda: a[5])
btn2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```